# How to check if the user is new upon authentication in Firebase V9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In v8 I was doing like that :

```js
const userCredential = await firebase.auth().signInAnonymously();
console.log('is new user: ', userCredential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser());
```

However in V9 :

```js
const userCredential = await SignInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider);
try {
  userCredential.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser()
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
  /* [!] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isNewUser') */
}
```

`additionalUserInfo` does not exist on the `UserCredential` object returned by the signin function.
What's the proper way to do it in V9?

Comment: There's a new [`getAdditionalUserInfo()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#getadditionaluserinfo) function in V9 SDK to read the `isNewUser` prop. Check the linked answer for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sign-in succeeded, the `UserCredentials` object you get back contains a [`user` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.usercredential.md#usercredentialuser) with the current user. You can determine whether this is a new user by comparing the `creationTime` and `lastSignInTime` of its [`metadata` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user.md#usermetadata). If they are no more than a few milliseconds apart, the user was just created.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I saw these values before but I wasn't sure if it was safe to use them in this calculation.
I have no access to the source code but I guess this is also what `getAdditionalUserInfo()` does internally to calculate the returned `isNewUser` value as well?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. If I recall correctly, the `isNewUser` was only added when one of the engineers on the team discovered there might be a small offset between the `creationTime` and `lastSignInTime` for new users so a simple `==` comparison isn't good enough.